# Slow build time

Tags: ros, navigation, catkin, ros-kinetic, voxel-grid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am experiencing very slow builds (and I have been for a while) using catkin_make building the ROS navigation stack. I have tried `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`, `--use-ninga`, `ccache`, etc but the problem still persists. Specifically, clean builds sometimes take me over an hour on a modern machine (i7 w/ 8GB RAM).

The build process proceeds rather quickly until it seems to stall out at 100%. A quick `htop` reveals that the culprit is a couple of linking threads that are taking 100% CPU and often are `costmap_2d` or trajectory planner related.

Has anyone seen this before or have any insight on how to fix this?

---

### Additional Information

```
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS  
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10)  
cmake version 3.5.1  
ROS Version: Kinetic
```

ROS Install: ROS installed from .debs (desktop-full) and upgraded w/ apt

Steps to reproduce:

```
mkdir -p ~/test/src  
cd ~/test/src  
catkin_init_workspace  
git clone https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation.git  
git checkout kinetic-devel  
cd ..
catkin_make  
... wait ...
```

Total Build Time: 22.5 min

The build got to 100% after <5min with the last message printed ... `

```
[100%] Built target move_base_node
```

Then 15 min later ...

```
[100%] Built target costmap_2d_cloud
[100%] Built target costmap_2d_markers
Base path: /home/patrick/test
Source space: /home/patrick/test/src
Build space: /home/patrick/test/build
Devel space: /home/patrick/test/devel
Install space: /home/patrick/test/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/patrick/test/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/patrick/test/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/patrick/test/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/patrick/test/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j6 -l6" in "/home/patrick/test/build"
####
```

The full output of catkin_make is available here ... https://pastebin.com/ZkFUqU2s

---

### Additional Information - Second Round

Memory consumption during the first 5 minutes of the build ...

```
patrick@patrick:~/test$ free -mh
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.2G        4.1G        222M        1.1G        2.9G        1.5G
Swap:          7.4G        3.2G        4.3G
```

After reaching the 100% ...

```
patrick@patrick:~/test$ free -mh
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.2G        4.6G        180M        1.2G        2.5G        1.0G
Swap:          7.4G        3.2G        4.2G
```

It looks like there should be plenty of free memory right?

Also, here are the processes that are "stalling" out in the second 15min of the build ...
https://pastebin.com/CDb2qLQs

Specifically, the /usr/bin/ld threads (there are 2, costmap_2d_cloud and costmap_2d_markers) which are taking 100% CPU

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303209/slow-build-time/) by [baronep](https://answers.ros.org/users/23631/baronep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2018-09-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-13**:
Please add some information about your system: which OS is this, which version, how did you install ROS (`.deb`s or completely from source), which and what version of compiler do you have installed, CMake version and what exactly you are building (ie: pkgs).

**Comment by [baronep](https://answers.ros.org/users/23631/baronep/) on 2018-09-13**:
Added additional information in the post above

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-09-13**:
What does your memory usage look like during that time?

**Comment by [baronep](https://answers.ros.org/users/23631/baronep/) on 2018-09-13**:
Added additional information above

**Comment by [baronep](https://answers.ros.org/users/23631/baronep/) on 2018-09-14**:
Just an observation, if I comment out the costmap_2d_cloud and costmap_2d_markers targets in the CMakelists.txt, my build reduces from >20min to ~3min. What about these 2 targets would make them have such a dramatic impact? voxel_grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've replicated your problem. It's hanging on the linking step, but you can fix it by adding ${catkin_LIBRARIES} to the target_link_libraries command for costmap-2d_cloud and markers. Not sure why yet, but I'm going to investigate and make a PR.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2018-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-10-12**:
https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/pull/800